# Unable to send mail using action mailer production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-compute-engine, actionmailer

I am able to send mail in development mode but it fails with following error on production mode.
**SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)**

My action mailer settings are

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => 'smtp.listup.co.in',
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               =>'listup.co.in',
      :user_name            => ENV['username'],
      :password             => ENV['password'],
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

My code is deployed on google compute engine. I tried changing the port with same error.

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654350/socketerror-getaddrinfo-name-or-service-not-known-sunspot-solr-rails-develo

Comment: Maybe its due to a firewall on Google Compute? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls

Comment: @Arv Thanks. It worked. I saw that post before but i was reluctant to try as i had no hope of that working.