# Rye::Box commands failing on remote server

Tags: sockets, rubygems

Firstly, I can ssh into the remote server and execute the following commands

```
cd public_html
du -sh
```

each successful & exiting with code **0**.

Automating the process with Rye::Box & with option *safe: false*

```
rbox.cd :public_html
```

does change directory but also returns exit code **-1**

```
rbox.execute 'du -sh'
```

fails with error message "**SocketError::getaddrinfo: Name or service not known**"

Would appreciate an explanation if possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Check your hosts entry for 127.0.0.1

You might have to add a hostname in `/etc/hosts` for 127.0.0.1.

A similar question addresses this issue on SO.

### See also

- [SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) - Sunspot/Solr Rails development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654350)