# Redmine cant recognize domain/hostname but I can send emails from command line

Tags: docker, email, redmine

I am using this project for dockerizing redmine https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/redmine/ but I am also using `helpdesk plugin`, so I can reply on tickets and send them back to the customer via redmine.

But I just ran into problem, which I can't solve for few days. I have postfix relay server on external server which works for most of my projects `smtpinternal.domain.tld`

I have this in my redmine config like this

```
# default configuration options for all environments
default: 
  # Outgoing emails configuration
  # See the examples below and the Rails guide for more configuration options:
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: false
      address: 'smtp.smtpinternal.domain.tld'
      port: 25
      domain: 'smtpinternal.domain.tld'
      tls: false
```

Sadly, when I want in my redmine instance try to send test email I have this error message

```
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

weird thing is that, I wanted to send test email with `mail utility` in the container, to test if I can resolve hostnames, and it worked. I can even ping on my `Nameservers` .. any idea, why redmine refuse to send emails?

Comment: If you are using postfix as relay, then you shouldn't be sending from Redmine with smtp. I think that you need to configure it something like this https://serverfault.com/questions/462982/how-to-use-sendmail-to-send-to-remote-smtp-postfix-relay

Comment: Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654350/socketerror-getaddrinfo-name-or-service-not-known-sunspot-solr-rails-develo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilder whole docker project and it worked.