# The application encountered the following error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError) in Kubernetes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes

I have configured my rails application in Kubernetes cloud server. I am able push all required images to docker hub and same configured in Kubernetes cloud server.All servers are running.I have created load balancer service to access my application.When I am to launch the url I am getting below error  from Pod.I have used passenger server in my application. How to resolve this issue.

```
[ E 2021-03-31 03:30:20.3057 70/Tl5w age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /DevieApp: The application encountered the following error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
  Error ID: 85cb9eaa
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-VHFeT8.html
```

Comment: Did you tested the application locally before deploying it? It might be possible that there some [host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654350/socketerror-getaddrinfo-name-or-service-not-known-sunspot-solr-rails-develo/9654650) wrongly configured. Can you update your question with some code example? Especially the part which is reponsible for paths/address/ports? I'm not an exert in ruby but it would be much easier for me to have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052791/configuring-rails-application-in-kubernates

Comment: I have created new post.I have added all the details.pls check